# Why " sql does not work very well with large clusters of boxes - Martin Fowler "?

Tags: sql, database, nosql-aggregation, nosql

I was trying to understand where NoSQL shines and finally landed in this video by Martin Fowler [here](https://youtu.be/qI_g07C_Q5I?t=308) , where he states that

```
"sql does not work very well with large clusters of boxes".
```

[image]

Why does he say so ?

What in SQL or relational databases made it unfit for working in large clusters ?

What is that NOSQL did to fix this and make it efficient when run in clusters ?

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34892/why-cant-rdbms-cluster-the-way-nosql-does

Comment: Thank you. That answers my question .